# Javascript: Stop iteration of a loop from outside with a boolean

Tags: javascript, loops, boolean

Task:

Find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both, as well as by all sequential numbers in the range between these parameters.

The code checks if all the elements have the same
smallest perfect divisor, and it comes to a point, where all elements
return true. The problem is that it doesn’t stop the iteration. There
is an  `iterate boolean` , which turns to false at the end, but then
at the beginning it gets assigned to true again. Is there a way to fix
that? Or is there another way to make this work?

The code below is set to iterate 8 times. That’s the point where it
should stop. If set to 9, it just goes on.

When the problem will be fixed the hard coded for loop will be changed
to  `while (iteration)` , if that’s OK?

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {

      let newArr = arr.sort();
      // get the numbers between the two elements
      let numbers = [];
      let secondElement = arr[1];
      for (let i = 0; i < secondElement; i++) {
        numbers.push(newArr[1]--);
      }
      console.log(numbers);


      // find the smallest common perfect divisor
      function findCommon(array) {

        let newArray = [...array]
        let multiplier = newArray[0];
        let product = 0;
        let iterate = true;
        // multiply the first element with multiplier
        // and store the product
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          if (iterate) {
            product = newArray[0] * multiplier++;
            console.log('product', product);
            console.log('multiplier', multiplier);
          }
        }
        // check which elements of the
        // array have a perfect division
        // with the product
        // and push the boolean results in a array,
        let booleans = [];
        for (j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
          booleans.push(product % newArray[j] === 0);
        }

        // count the elements that are true
        let trueValues = 0;
        for (let k = 0; k < booleans.length; k++) {
          if (booleans[k] === true) {
            trueValues++
          }
        }

        console.log(booleans);
        console.log('trueValues', trueValues);


        console.log('iterate', iterate);
        // if all elements are true, stop iteration.
        if (trueValues === newArray.length) {
          iterate = false;
        }
        console.log('iterate', iterate);

        return product;

      }

      let result = findCommon(numbers);

      return result;
    }

    console.log('result', smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```

Comment: Please don't use blockquote incorrectly. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52873413/edit) the question so that only the part you're **actually quoting** is in blockquotes.

Comment: *"Here is the jsbin..."* Instead of an off-site link, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: *"There is an `iterate` `boolean`"* Not in the question.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you for your comments. I think now it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code works!

```js
    function smallestCommons(arr) {

      let newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

      // get the numbers between the two elements
      let numbers = [];
      let firstElement = newArr[0]
      let secondElement = newArr[1];
      for (let i = 0; i < secondElement; i++) {
        while (firstElement <= secondElement) {
          numbers.push(secondElement--)
        }
      }
     


      // find the smallest common perfect divisor
      function findCommon(array) {

        let newArray = [...array]
        let multiplier = newArray[0];
        let product = 0;
        let booleans = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
          booleans.push(false)
        }

        // Multiply the first element with multiplier
        // and store the product.
        // Check the product with each value from the
        // newArray, for a perfect division.
        // Increment the multiplier and check again.
        // In every iteration remover the first value from
        // the newArray and add the result of the
        // new check at the end (FIFO).
        // If all values are true break the booleans loop
        // If all values are true break the outer loop.

        for (;;) {
          product = newArray[0] * multiplier;
          //  console.log('product', product);
          //  console.log('multiplier', multiplier);
          for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            //  console.log('newArray', newArray[i]);
            //  console.log('1', booleans);
            booleans.shift()
            booleans.push(product % newArray[i] === 0);
            //console.log(booleans);
            let pass = booleans.every(x => x === true)
            //  console.log('pass', pass);
            if (pass) {
              break;
            }
            //    console.log("booleans", booleans);
          }
          let pass2 = booleans.every(x => x === true)
          if (pass2) {
            break;
          }
          //  console.log('2', pass2);
          multiplier++
        }
        return product;
      }
      return findCommon(numbers);;
    }
    console.log('result', smallestCommons([23, 18]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The previews solution is not efficient.

```js
  
    function smallestCommons(arr) {

      arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);

      // get the numbers between the two elements
      let inBetweenNums = [];
      for (let i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
        inBetweenNums.push(i)
      }

      // find the smallest common perfect divisor
      let multiplier = 2;
      let product = 0;
      let dividesCleanly = true;

      // Multiply the first two numbers with a multiplier.
      // Check if the product divides perfectly all the numbers
      // If there is a number that doesn't divide perfectly
      // break the loop. So after break, dividesCleanly = true, which
      // is the else, doesn't execute. The dividesCleanly is false
      // so the product does not get returned. So we go to
      // decrement multiplier, and so on.
      // While there is a number that doesn't divide perfectly,
      // the loop will break and the product will never be returned.

      while (true) {
        product = inBetweenNums[0] * inBetweenNums[1] * multiplier;
        //console.log('prod... ', product);
        for (let i = 0; i < inBetweenNums.length; i++) {
         // console.log('inBe...1 ', inBetweenNums[i]);
          if (product % inBetweenNums[i] !== 0) {
           // console.log(inBetweenNums[i]);
            dividesCleanly = false;
            break;
          }
          dividesCleanly = true;
         // console.log(dividesCleanly);
        }
        if (dividesCleanly) {
         // console.log(product);
          return product
        } else {
          multiplier++
        }
      }
    }

   console.log('result', smallestCommons([23, 18]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is with a do while loop instead of while(true)

```js
    function smallestCommons(arr) {

      arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);

      // get the numbers between the two elements
      let inBetweenNums = [];
      for (let i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
        inBetweenNums.push(i)
      }

      // find the smallest common perfect divisor
      let multiplier = 2;
      let product = 0;
      let i = 0;

      do {
        product = inBetweenNums[0] * inBetweenNums[1] * multiplier;
        //  console.log('prod... ', product);
        for (i = 0; i < inBetweenNums.length; i++) {
          //console.log('1.. ', i);
          if (product % inBetweenNums[i] !== 0) {
            //  console.log(inBetweenNums[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
        multiplier++

        //console.log('1.. ', i);
      } while (i !== inBetweenNums.length)
      //  console.log(product);
      return product
    }

    console.log('result', smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```